# How to give a Class name to an initial Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, classname

I am developing a swift application, which uses a Walkthrough screen as initial view controller when the app is launched for its first time. 
I have a skip button there, which should dismiss it when the user clicks on it. The Problem occurs with the action of the button, where I have a code and inside the code I have to assign a name for the first TabBarViewController (the main screen in the app). Please look at the picture:
[image]

Would you please help me how to give a Class Name to this initial TabBar  Controller,I successfully created a Storyboard ID in my case(InitialViewController), but I can't give a class name, look at the picture:
[image]
I have never done this before, I tried to create a new CocoaTouch file and assign a name TabBar Controller, but when I go to the Main StoryBoard and try to type the name inside, it is not recognised.  Any ideas how to assign a class name to it ?

Comment: did you create a class? how do you want to add a name if you did not create a name?

Comment: Any other files on your screen contain a class? did you write anything in swift? try some tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `TabBarController` is a regular `UITabBarController`
In that case your code should look like this:

```
let nextView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InitialViewController") as! UITabBarController
// force unwrapping for brevity
```

Comment: Thanks man that is the answer I needed. Awesome solution, thank you so much. Vote Up from me ! I appreciate it!

Comment: no problem, please don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You must have selected it to be a subclass of UIViewController, however, right now you want it to be a Sub-class of UITabViewController.